# With statement destructor to catch init exceptions

Tags: python, destructor, init, with-statement

I use a with statement with the following class.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    print "EXIT Shutting the SDK down"
    ret = self.sdkobject.ShutDown()
    self.error_check(ret)
```

This catches any error that occur when I am using the object of the class and safely shuts down the SDK that I am using. However, it catch problems when the class is still initializing. I have recently found the "del" function which neatly solves this problem. However, it can't be used in conjunction with the exit function (as the with statement evokes the exit and the del gets an exception). How can I set up a destructor using a with statemtent, which will catch failures even during initialization?

Comment: You mean that exceptions in `__init__` need to trigger a shutdown too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate `shutdown` function that gets called in the `try/except` block of the `__init__` and wherever else you need a proper shutdown.

Comment: Are try except statements OK in the __init__ class?

Comment: @Marmstrong: Yes. Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: Yeah sprinkle them away wherever needed.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions in the `__init__` need to be dealt with directly *in* that method:

```
class YourContextManager(object):
    sdkobject = None

    def __init__(self):
        try:
             self._create_sdk_object()
        except Exception:
             if self.sdkobject is not None:
                 self.sdkobject.ShutDown()
             raise

    def _create_sdk_object(self):
        self.sdkobject = SomeSDKObject()
        self.sdkobject.do_something_that_could_raise_an_exception()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print "EXIT Shutting the SDK down"
        ret = self.sdkobject.ShutDown()
        self.error_check(ret)
```

Note that the exception is re-raised; you want to give the consumer of the context manager an opportunity to handle the failure to create a context manager.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception in `__init__` and handle it. `__del__` is unnecessary.